# I am trying to print the name of the list but somehow the reference from the arraylist is not working?

Tags: java

Customer is a class. The Class list is arraylist of Customer. 
I have added the Customers to list but when I want to print all the customer names from the list I get null only.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Assignment1 {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    List list = new List();
    list.addCustomer("man");
    list.addCustomer("man");
    //System.out.println(list);
    list.printx();


  }
}
class Customer{
  public String name;
  public Customer(String name)
  {
    name = this.name;
  }
}

class List 
{

  ArrayList<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();

  public void addCustomer(String name1)
  {
    Customer x = new Customer(name1);
    list.add(x);
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
  }


  public void printx()
  {
    for(int i =0;i < list.size();i++)
    {
      System.out.println(list.get(i).name);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Assignment puts the value on the right into the variable on the left, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your `Customer` constructor, you need to set ::

```
this.name = name;
```

and not the other way round! :P

What you have done right now is that you change the function parameter `name` to the class parameter `name` which is currently `null`(default initialization). So, you never initialize `name` variable of the `Customer` class, and hence you always get `null` when you print it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you override the `toString` method in class `Customer`, it helps you debug your `Customer` objects. For example, you can change the local variable to `assignedName` as below:

```
   class Customer{
        public String name;
        public Customer(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "customer name:" + this.name;
        }
    }
```

`this.name` and `name` are different things in the `Customer` constructor:
`this.name` is an instance variable and `name` is a local variable defined in your constructor.

```
// you should narrow the modifier to private, and implement getter and setter for it
public String name;
public Customer(String assignedName){
    this.name = assignedName;
}
```